# Binding custom QML object types defined in C++ as if they are properties

Tags: qt, qml

In the context of QML property binding, I would like to understand how to bind two custom QML types defined in C++ (not their properties).

I have a C++ class `Service` containing a `PortApp` (custom type) attribute :

```
class Service:
        public ServiceBase
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Service(string serviceName);
    ...
    Q_PROPERTY(PortApp* pa READ x_get WRITE x_set NOTIFY signalpaChanged)

    PortApp *x_get(){
        pa.setParent(const_cast<QObject*>((QObject*)this));
        return & pa;
    };

    void x_set(PortApp *objIn){
        pa = *objIn;
        pa.setParent(const_cast<QObject*>((QObject*)this));
        emit signalpaChanged();
    };
    PortApp pa;
...
```

The class instance is available to QML as a context property:

```
_ptrQmlAppEngine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("srvUiPlantLayout", specs._ptrServiceBase);
```

PortApp class is registered in the Qt meta type system and available to QML as well:

```
qRegisterMetaType<PortApp>("PortApp");
qmlRegisterType<PortApp>("domain", 1, 0, "PortApp");

...
class PortApp:
        public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    PortApp(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    PortApp(const PortApp &other);
    PortApp &operator=(const PortApp &other);

    ...some attributes exposed as Q_PROPERTYes  with their signal

};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(PortApp)
```

I'm able to access srvUiPlantLayout, access its properties (pa among the others) but I'm not able to properly bind instances of PortApp among QML files. More specifically.
somefile.qml:

```
TableRecipeLink{
     id: idRecipeLink
     ...
     paView: srvUiPlantLayout.pa
     myPaTest1: srvUiPlantLayout.pa
     myPaTest2: srvUiPlantLayout.pa
}
```

TableRecipeLink.qml:

```
Item {
    id: root
    ...
    property alias paView: idModel.pa
    property PortApp myPaTest1: PortApp{}
    property PortApp myPaTest2

    onMyPaTest1Changed: {
        console.error("myPaTest1 changed")
    }

    onMyPaTest2Changed: {
        console.error("myPaTest2 changed")
    }

    model: UiRecipePortLinkModel{
        id: idModel
        pa: root.paView
    }
```

`onMyPaTest1Changed` and `onMyPaTest2Changed` are called only **once** and even if `srvUiPlantLayout` emits `signalpaChanged()`  callbacks are never called a second time. What am I doing wrong? I already tried several approaches:

```
Connections{
     target: srvUiPlantLayout
     function onSignalpaChanged(){
         myPaTest2= srvUiPlantLayout.pa
     }
}
```

and also bindings:

```
Binding {
    target: root
    property: "myPaTest2"
    value: srvUiPlantLayout.pa
}
```

None of them worked.

Apparently such binding instead works between C++ objects: `idModel`'s `slotpaChanged()` is always called when srvUiPlantLayout emits a signal:

```
class UiRecipePortLinkModel:
        public UiModelBaseTable
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    UiRecipePortLinkModel(QObject *parent)
    :UiModelBaseTable(parent)
    {
        ...
        connect(this, SIGNAL(signalpaChanged()), this, SLOT(slotpaChanged()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE void refresh();

    Q_PROPERTY_OBJ(PortApp, pa) //a macro for Q_PROPERTY(PortApp *pa, READ ... WRITE... NOTIFY...)

    ...
};
```

This makes me think that `paView: srvUiPlantLayout.pa` does its job of binding the C++ objects as properties while `myPaTest1: srvUiPlantLayout.pa` fail. Is there any reason for this behavior?

Comment: I'm assuming it's because the value hasn't actually changed. Emitting signalpaChanged() tells myPaTest1 to reevaluate, but if it's still pointing to the same value it might not emit its own myPaTest1Changed signal. Are you actually changing the PortApp value?

Comment: @JarMan: `myPaTest1` is always re-assigned to the same object `srvUiPlantLayout.pa` so I should say its value never changes in the sense that `srvUiPlantLayout.pa` memory address never changes. But its contents do change and I can see from the debugger that myPaTest1 values always match the update values. This is actually weird: everything get updated but I don't know when. Does it mean I should bind every single class attribute instead of the whole object?

Comment: If I had `property Item someThing: myItem`, and then did `myItem.width = 100`, I would not expect to see a `someThingChanged` signal. It's still pointing at the same object, even if the object's content changed.

Comment: Because PortApp is a member and not created. The lifestyle also doesn't belong in the QML/JS engine, it's declared in the C++ class and is destroyed with the class. Perhaps it need not be a QObject. Consider using Q_GADGET instead.

Comment: @JarMan me neither. But in my case the backend emits something changed(), so the only way I can understand this is that someThing keeps the same memory address. Stephen: portApp is actually created in TableRecipeLink.qml. Indeed it's ctor is called. Q_GADGET is out of scope in my case since the class has be instantiated in QML.

Comment: In my example, I should have named `myItem` to be `myBackendItem` for clarity. You're getting a signal that the backend item changed, but the binding just causes a reevaluation of `someThing`, not a guaranteed change. It most likely does something like this underneath: `if (someThing != myBackendItem) { someThing = myBackendItem; someThingChanged(); }` So it will only emit the signal if the object changed. It's not comparing the contents.

Comment: @JarMan: I got your point and for sure that is what's happening. I feel this is totally wrong: such != operator should be related to the class operator!=. So my initial question remains: how to bind such objects (contents)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JarMan's perspective I think I got it. My objective is to bind QML objects types defined in C++ between QML files. This is not possible in QML. These objects have Q_PROPERTYes, so the C++ classes must inherit from `QObject`. Since QObject is not copyable, in QML I'm binding pointers instead of class instances. Emitting signals on class instances will not produce any callback on the QML side (this is what happens in the code shown in the question) since the source pointer is always the same.

My error was in `UiRecipePortLinkModel`:

```
Q_PROPERTY(PortApp* pa READ x_get WRITE x_set NOTIFY signalpaChanged)

PortApp *x_get(){
    pa.setParent(const_cast<QObject*>((QObject*)this));
    return & pa;
};

void x_set(PortApp *objIn){
    pa = *objIn;
    pa.setParent(const_cast<QObject*>((QObject*)this));
    emit signalpaChanged();
};
PortApp pa;
```

I was keeping an instance of PortApp (`PortApp pa`) instead of a pointer. I changed the code in this way:

```
class UiRecipePortLinkModel:
        public UiModelBaseTable
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    UiRecipePortLinkModel(QObject *parent = nullptr)
    :UiModelBaseTable(parent, "ui_recipe_port_link_model")
    {
        roleMap[Qt::DisplayRole] = "item";
        connect(this, SIGNAL(signalpaChanged()), this, SLOT(slotpaChanged()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
    }

    ...
    Q_PROPERTY(PortApp * pa WRITE pa_set NOTIFY signalpaChanged)
    void pa_set(PortApp *objIn){
        pa = objIn;
        pa->setParent(const_cast<QObject*>((QObject*)this));
        emit signalpaChanged();
    }
    PortApp *pa = nullptr;
    ...

public slots:
    void slotpaChanged()
    {
        LOG_ERR("slotpaChanged()");
        ...connect signals from the new pa to the appropriate slot to refresh the model...
    }
```

The first time `pa` is assigned `slotpaChanged()` is called, subscribing `UiRecipePortLinkModel` to all changes to `pa` properties signalled by the originator. If `pa` is reassigned, again the connection process restarts.

In this way `UiRecipePortLinkModel` is self-contained (do not depend on context properties) and can react to any changes made to `pa` contents, wherever the come from.

**Addendum**: for me the tricky part was to understand how to declare a pointer to such classes in QML. Well, I did this experiment:

```
Item {
    id: idRoot

    PortApp{
        id: idPa1
    }

    property PortApp idPa2: PortApp{
        id: idPa3
    }

    property PortApp idPa4: idPa1

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.error("idPa4: " + idPa4)
    }
```

I also added log statement on PortApp constructor printing the memory address of class instances. Here the results:

```
[2023/07/07 20:01:44:129] [info] [plant_app.cpp:15] - ctor 0xa56ba3d0
[2023/07/07 20:01:44:129] [info] [plant_app.cpp:15] - ctor 0xa56baa80
[2023/07/07 20:01:44:142] [info] [ChamberView.qml:41] - idPa4: PortApp(0x5574a56baa80)
```

So idPa1,3 are objects, while idPa4 and idPa2 are the pointers I was looking for!